# WPF richTextBox cant identify as UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, adorner, uielement

I have the following code which attaches `Adorner`s to `UIElement`s which I have on a `Canvas`.

```
private void slideCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  {
                selected = false;
                if (selectedElement != null)
                {
                    aLayer.Remove(aLayer.GetAdorners(selectedElement)[0]);
                    selectedElement = null;
                }
            }

            if (e.Source != slideCanvas)
            {
                _isDown = true;
                _startPoint = e.GetPosition(slideCanvas);

                selectedElement = e.Source as UIElement;

                _originalLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(selectedElement);
                _originalTop = Canvas.GetTop(selectedElement);

                aLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(selectedElement);
                aLayer.Add(new ResizingAdorner(selectedElement));
                selected = true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
}
```

For some reason though when I click on a `RichTextBox` during runtime the program crashes as the `RichTextBox` is not found by `e.Source` as `UIElement`.

`selectedElement` will just be `null`.

Can anybody tell me why and give me a work around please?

Comment: You may set a breakpoint at that line to see what `e.Source` actually is. Maybe it's one of the document elements inside the RichTextBox.

Comment: e.Source is {System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument}. I'm not really sure what that means can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `e.Source` is the [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx) of the RichTextBox that you clicked on. It is a `FlowDocument`, which is not derived from `UIElement`.

You may however access the RichTextBox by the FlowDocument's `Parent` property.

```
if (e.Source is FlowDocument)
{
    selectedElement = ((FlowDocument)e.Source).Parent as UIElement;
}
else
{
    selectedElement = e.Source as UIElement;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Now I can click and move and resize the RichTextBox but I cant actually type anything in. I am attaching adorners to resize and move controls about on the Canvas. Will it be that my previewLeftMouseButtonDown event is firing before I can type anything in the RichTextBox?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Except when you navigate focus by keyboard, with the Tab key. If your adorner is for indicating input focus, you may better attach handlers to the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) and [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus.aspx) events. Or Got/LostKeyboardFocus.